# Will light continue traveling after the source has stopped producing light?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light

Will light continue traveling after the source has stopped producing light?

Comment: Two words: pulsed laser.

Comment: Think about fiber optics. Light travels through fiber at about 1 foot per nanosecond. If the laser is signalling at 1 Gb/s (fairly slow, nowadays), and the fiber is 1000 feet long, that means by the time a pulse reaches the receiver, the source has conceivably stopped and started signalling 1000 times since that pulse was generated.

Comment: What do you think, and why?  PLease check the posting guidelines & you'll get better responses.

Comment: Why would light *already emitted* stop when the source stops emitting?

Comment: @KyleKanos - If the OP could answer your question, he probably would not have asked this question in the first place :-)

Answer (score 1):

Light travels with velocity c until it hits something or goes off to large distances in vacuum, as the light that comes to us from the sun and the stars.

Light is composed out of zillions of [photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon), the photon being one of the  [elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) which make up matter. Their path has a beginning in time. When the source stops producing light it stops producing photons . The pulse of light will go on until it hits something.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, All light (photons) emited from the source will continue traveling even if the source disapears.
Since light travels at the speed of light "c", what happens is that any viewer closer than  the product of c and the time elapsed since the destruction of the source, would no longer be able to see the source.

Viewers at greater distance will continue seing the source (receiving its light) until the time comes when the last photons emited reach the distance of this observer.
This happens in reality where we can observe stars as they where millions of years ago, and will continue seing them for years even if they have now disapeared.

Another example is with radio comunication, even though it is not considered light because of diferent frequency it is same principle. 
A space probe in Mars sends a  message to earth, with pictures and its status. It takes say 10 minutes for the signal to reach earth. If the probe is landing on Mars and transmiting on its way down, but then crashes, Mission control will however still be able to recieve the probes transmissions previous to crashing even up to ten minutes after the probe disapeared because of crashing with Mars.